# Are you allowed to give a Jewish driver directions to your shul on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, vehicles-transportation

While you are walking to the synagogue on Shabbat, a Jewish driver stops his car and asks you how to drive to that synagogue. Is there any problem giving him the directions? Are you facilitating or encouraging him to do a melacha?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDvrplQqeQ4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rabbi Benjamin Yasgur quotes Nechama Leibowitz, who said that Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach ruled that yes, you are allowed to give him directions, for two reasons:

1. If you don't answer, the driver might commit additional violations if they choose the wrong way.
2. Not answering might create animosity (איבה) between Jews.

Source: [TorahMusings.com](http://www.torahmusings.com/2013/01/directions-on-shabbos/)

Comment: This was the practice of many great rabbis. Surprisingly, Rabbi Aaron Lichtenstein shlit'a is of the opinion that you apologize and say you don't know.